# How to get context in service outside of onStartCommand() method?

Tags: android, service, android-service

When I use Intent outside of onStartCommand() of service, to show notification on a specific event, it shows getApplicationContext on the null object reference.
Service only allow to use getApplcationContext/this/context inside the onStartCommand() method.
How can I use it outside of onStartCommand() method?
Below is my Service. Can someone help me out with this?

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    @Nullable

    private static TransferUtility transferUtility;
    private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> transferRecordMaps;
    private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> transferRecordMaps1;
    private Utils utils = new Utils();
    private static final int INDEX_NOT_CHECKED = -1;
    public static int totalcount, totalAssetCount;
    private int checkedIndex;
    private static List<TransferObserver> observers;
    private static int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, navigate = 0,counter=0,failedcounter=0;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";
    UploadMediaToAssetFragment uploadMediaToAssetFragment;
    private int progress;
    Context context;
    private long currentbyte, totalbyte;
    private Notification notification;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        transferUtility = Util.getTransferUtility(getApplicationContext());
        checkedIndex = INDEX_NOT_CHECKED;
        transferRecordMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        transferRecordMaps1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        uploadMediaToAssetFragment = new UploadMediaToAssetFragment();


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, UploadMediaToAssetFragment.class);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"bytes"+UploadMediaToAssetFragment.totalAssetCount+ " total"+UploadMediaToAssetFragment.totalcount);

            uploadAsset();
            initData();
            updateList();
//            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//                    builder.setTitle("Test dialog");
//                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
//                    builder.setMessage("Content");
//
//                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
//            alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
//                alert.show();

            // startActivity(notificationIntent);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);

            Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
            PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    previousIntent, 0);

            Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    playIntent, 0);

            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    nextIntent, 0);

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.logo);
             notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Visibly")
                    .setTicker("asset uplaoding")
                    .setContentText("uploading")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(
                            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                     .setProgress(100,progress,false)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel,
                            "cancel", ppreviousIntent).build();
            startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                    notification);

//            if(UploadMediaToAssetFragment.totalAssetCount>=UploadMediaToAssetFragment.totalcount)
//            {
//                onDestroy();
//                stopForeground(true);
//                stopSelf();
//            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Previous");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Next");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
    }
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public class ForegroundServiceBInder extends Binder {
        ForegroundService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return ForegroundService.this;
        }
    }


    public void uploadAsset()
    {
        Log.d("upload asset service","method called");
        for(int i=0;i<AddMediaAssetActivity.galleryDTOArrayList1.size();i++)
        {
            Handler handler1 = new Handler();
            try {
                if(AddMediaAssetActivity.galleryDTOArrayList1.get(i)!=null)
                {
                    String path;
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(AddMediaAssetActivity.galleryDTOArrayList1.get(i).getMediaName()));
                    path = Utility.getPath(uri, getApplicationContext());
                    Uri uriThumb = Uri.fromFile(new File(AddMediaAssetActivity.galleryDTOArrayList1.get(i).getThumbnail()));
                    String pathThum = null;
                    if (uriThumb != null)
                        pathThum = Utility.getPath(uriThumb, getApplicationContext());
                    path = Utility.getPath(uri, getApplicationContext());
                    if(GlobalVariables.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                        beginUpload1(pathThum, pathThum);

                        beginUpload(path, AddMediaAssetActivity.galleryDTOArrayList1.get(i).getDescription(), pathThum,AddMediaAssetActivity.galleryDTOArrayList1.get(i).getCreateTagPostDTOList());
                    }else
                    {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(),android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
                        } else {
                            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        }
                        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.network_connectivity))
                                .setTitle("");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                            {
                                //getApplicationContext().finish();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                        dialog.show();
                        dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.clear_blue));

                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Begins to upload the file specified by the file path.
     */
    private void beginUpload(String filePath, String title, String pathThum, List<TagDTO> createTagPostDTOList)
    {
        Log.d("beginUpload","method called "+filePath+" title "+title+" pathnum "+pathThum+" list tagdto"+createTagPostDTOList);
        if (filePath == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find the filepath of the selected file",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        File file = new File(filePath);
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, Constants.FOLDERNAME_NAME+"/"+ file.getName(),
                file, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        File file1 = new File(pathThum);
        AssetMediaDTO assetMediaDTO=new AssetMediaDTO();
        if(GlobalVariables.isCampaignAsset)
        {
            if (GlobalVariables.campaignFeedDTO.getCampaign_category() != null && GlobalVariables.campaignFeedDTO.getCampaign_category().length() > 0 && !(GlobalVariables.campaignFeedDTO.getCampaign_category().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))) {
                assetMediaDTO.setCategory_id(GlobalVariables.campaignFeedDTO.getCampaign_category());
            } else {
                assetMediaDTO.setCategory_id("rpPDp");
            }
            if (GlobalVariables.campaignFeedDTO.getCampaign_folder() != null && GlobalVariables.campaignFeedDTO.getCampaign_folder().length() > 0 && !(GlobalVariables.campaignFeedDTO.getCampaign_folder().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))) {
                if(GlobalVariables.campaignFeedDTO.getCampaign_folder().equalsIgnoreCase("General"))
                {
                    assetMediaDTO.setFolder_id("");
                }else
                {
                    assetMediaDTO.setFolder_id(GlobalVariables.campaignFeedDTO.getCampaign_folder());
                }


            } else
            {
                assetMediaDTO.setFolder_id("");

            }
        }else
        {
            if (AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getCategoryID() != null && AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getCategoryID().length() > 0 && !(AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getCategoryID().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))) {
                assetMediaDTO.setCategory_id(AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getCategoryID());
            } else {
                assetMediaDTO.setCategory_id("rpPDp");
            }
            if (AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getFolderIdentity() != null && AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getFolderIdentity().length() > 0 && !(AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getFolderIdentity().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))) {

                if(AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getFoldername()!=null&&AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getFoldername().equalsIgnoreCase("general"))
                {
                    assetMediaDTO.setFolder_id("");
                }else {
                    assetMediaDTO.setFolder_id(AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getFolderIdentity());
                }

            } else {
                assetMediaDTO.setFolder_id("");

            }
        }
        assetMediaDTO.setMedia_url(GlobalVariables.s3Path+Constants.FOLDERNAME_NAME+"/"+file.getName());
        assetMediaDTO.setThumbnail_url(GlobalVariables.s3Path+Constants.FOLDERNAME_NAME+"/"+file1.getName());
        try {
            assetMediaDTO.setMediaSize(""+file.length());
        }catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        assetMediaDTO.setDetail(title);
        String result = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf("."));
        assetMediaDTO.setTitle(result);
        assetMediaDTO.setTagDTOList(createTagPostDTOList);
        GlobalVariables.assetMediaDTOList.add(assetMediaDTO);

    }


    /*
     * Begins to upload the file specified by the file path.
     */
    private void beginUpload1(String filePath, String pathThum) {
        Log.d("beginUpload1","method called");
        if (filePath == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find the filepath of the selected file",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        File file = new File(filePath);
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, Constants.FOLDERNAME_NAME+"/"+ file.getName(),
                file,CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
      //  temp1=file.getName();

    }


    //To delete assets from list
    public void deleteMediaUpload(final int position)
    {
        final int position1=position+1;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GlobalVariables.mActivity, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GlobalVariables.mActivity);
        }
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete this media?")
                .setTitle("");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (position >= 0 && position1 < observers.size())
                {
                    try {
                        transferUtility.deleteTransferRecord(observers.get(position).getId());
                        transferUtility.deleteTransferRecord(observers.get(position1).getId());
                        observers.remove(position1);
                        transferRecordMaps.remove(position1);
                        observers.remove(position);
                        transferRecordMaps.remove(position);
                        AddMediaAssetActivity.galleryDTOArrayList1.remove(position);
                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                    updateList();
                    try {
                        GlobalVariables.assetMediaDTOList.remove(position);
                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(GlobalVariables.mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.clear_blue));
        dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(GlobalVariables.mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.clear_blue));

    }

//    /**
//     * Gets all relevant transfers from the Transfer Service for populating the
//     * UI
//     */
//    private void initData() {
//        counter=0;
//        failedcounter=0;
//        navigate=0;
//        transferRecordMaps.clear();
//        transferRecordMaps1.clear();
//        // Use TransferUtility to get all upload transfers.
//        observers = transferUtility.getTransfersWithType(TransferType.UPLOAD);
//        TransferListener listener = new UploadMediaToAssetFragment.UploadListener();
//        for (TransferObserver observer : observers) {
//
//            // For each transfer we will will create an entry in
//            // transferRecordMaps which will display
//            // as a single row in the UI
//            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//            Util.fillMap(map, observer, false);
//
//            transferRecordMaps.add(map);
//
//            // Sets listeners to in progress transfers
//            if (TransferState.WAITING.equals(observer.getState())
//                    || TransferState.WAITING_FOR_NETWORK.equals(observer.getState())
//                    || TransferState.IN_PROGRESS.equals(observer.getState())) {
//                observer.setTransferListener(listener);
//            }
//        }
//        transferRecordMaps1.clear();
//        for(int i=0;i<transferRecordMaps.size();i++)
//        {
//            File file = new File((String) transferRecordMaps.get(i).get("fileName"));
//            if(file.getName().substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase("0!"))
//            {
//            }
//            else
//            {
//                transferRecordMaps1.add(transferRecordMaps.get(i));
//
//            }
//
//        }
//        assetListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//    }

    /*
     * A TransferListener class that can listen to a upload task and be notified
     * when the status changes.
     */
    public class UploadListener implements TransferListener {

        // Simply updates the UI list when notified.
        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception e)
        {
            failedcounter++;
            updateList();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

            updateList();

            currentbyte =bytesCurrent;
            totalbyte =bytesTotal;
            Log.d("onprogresschnaged","method bytes"+bytesCurrent+" bytestotoal"+bytesTotal);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState newState)
        {
            if (newState.equals(TransferState.COMPLETED))
            {
                counter++;
                updateList();
            } else if (newState.equals(TransferState.FAILED))
            {
                failedcounter++;
               updateList();
            }




        }

    }
    /*
     * Updates the ListView according to the observers.
     */
    /*
     * Updates the ListView according to the observers.
     */
    public void updateList()
    {
        if(transferRecordMaps!=null&&transferRecordMaps.size()>0)
        {
            TransferObserver observer = null;
            HashMap<String, Object> map = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++) {
                observer = observers.get(i);
                map = transferRecordMaps.get(i);
                 progress = (int) ((double) observer.getBytesTransferred() * 100 / observer
                        .getBytesTotal());

                Log.d("progressuploadingData"," map"+progress);

                Util.fillMap(map, observer, i == checkedIndex);
                Log.d("uploadingData"," map"+map+" observer"+observer);

            }
            transferRecordMaps1.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < transferRecordMaps.size(); i++)
            {
                File file = new File((String) transferRecordMaps.get(i).get("fileName"));
                if (file.getName().substring(0, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("0!")) {
                } else
                {
                    transferRecordMaps1.add(transferRecordMaps.get(i));

                }
                totalcount=transferRecordMaps.size();
                totalAssetCount=counter+failedcounter;
                Log.d("totalcount","count"+totalcount+"toatlassetcount"+totalAssetCount);
                if(counter>1&&totalAssetCount>=totalcount&&GlobalVariables.assetMediaDTOList.size()>0)
                {
                    Log.d("myservice asset","complete");
                    navigate=1;

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DialogeActivity.class);
                    context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

                   // Toast.makeText(this,"Your asset uploaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DialogeActivity.class);
//                    notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
//                    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
//                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//                    startActivity(notificationIntent);


//                    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
//                            .setContentTitle("Visibly")
//                            .setTicker("asset uploaded")
//                            .setContentText("asset uploaded successfully")
//                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
//                            .build();





//                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//                    builder.setTitle("Test dialog");
//                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
//                    builder.setMessage("Content");
//                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
//                            //Do something
//                            dialog.dismiss();
//                        });
//
//                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
//            alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
//                alert.show();

//                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
//                            .setTitle("Title")
//                            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
//                            .create();
//
//                    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
//                    alertDialog.show();
//                    button_Done.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    button_Done.setText("Done");
//                    button_Done.setEnabled(true);
//                    button_Done.setClickable(true);

                }else if(failedcounter>=totalcount)
                {
                    navigate=0;
//                    button_Done.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    button_Done.setText("Back");
//                    button_Done.setEnabled(true);
//                    button_Done.setClickable(true);
                }else
                {
//                    button_Done.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    button_Done.setText("Please wait.");
//                    button_Done.setEnabled(false);
//                    button_Done.setClickable(false);
                }
            }


           // assetListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else
        {
//            Intent intent=null;
//            if( AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO!=null&&AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getFolderIdentity()!=null&& AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getFolderIdentity().length()>0&&!AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO.getFolderIdentity().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
//                intent = new Intent(activity, AssetFolderActivity.class);
//            }else
//            {
//                intent = new Intent(activity, DashboardActivity.class);
//            }
//            intent.putExtra("folderDTO", AssetFolderActivity.folderDTO);
//            activity.startActivity(intent);
//            activity.finish();
        }

    }

    private void initData() {
        counter=0;
        failedcounter=0;
        navigate=0;
        transferRecordMaps.clear();
        transferRecordMaps1.clear();
        // Use TransferUtility to get all upload transfers.
        observers = transferUtility.getTransfersWithType(TransferType.UPLOAD);
        TransferListener listener =  new ForegroundService().new UploadListener();
        for (TransferObserver observer : observers) {

            // For each transfer we will will create an entry in
            // transferRecordMaps which will display
            // as a single row in the UI
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Util.fillMap(map, observer, false);

            transferRecordMaps.add(map);

            // Sets listeners to in progress transfers
            if (TransferState.WAITING.equals(observer.getState())
                    || TransferState.WAITING_FOR_NETWORK.equals(observer.getState())
                    || TransferState.IN_PROGRESS.equals(observer.getState())) {
                observer.setTransferListener(listener);
            }
        }
        transferRecordMaps1.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<transferRecordMaps.size();i++)
        {
            File file = new File((String) transferRecordMaps.get(i).get("fileName"));
            if(file.getName().substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase("0!"))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                transferRecordMaps1.add(transferRecordMaps.get(i));
            }

        }
       // assetListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: Get the context into a static variable inside onStartCommand() method, and then use it elsewhere.

Comment: Just use `ForegroundService.this`.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Where exactly are you getting `null` from `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: In the future please try to be more specific. Saying "It's not working" won't win you any friends around here, nor is it likely to animate anyone to try to help you. You've posted way too much code and you've not posted any stack trace or indicated where you get the exception. And you obviously haven't spent much time try to debug your code or figure out what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

> Service only allow to use getApplcationContext/this/context inside the onStartCommand() method

There is no such restriction. You can use it from other methods on your `Service`, so long as `onCreate()` has already been called on that `Service`.

So, to show a `Notification` from some background thread that your `Service` forks from `onStartCommand()`, for example, use `this`.

Comment: hello @CommonsWare can you help me with my question

Comment: @jack: It works for other developers. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Notifications/DownloadNotify) uses `this` from `onHandleIntent()` of an `IntentService` to raise a `Notification`. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Service/JobIntentService) uses `this` in `onHandleWork()` of a `JobIntentService` to send a local broadcast. If you have further problems, ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] of what *is not working* and explain in details what "not working" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not using Intentservice I am using service, in IntentService as we use onHandlework(), In Service, we use onStartCommand in which this works fine. but "this" not work in custom method in service

Comment: @jack: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] example of what is not working and explain in detail what "not work" means.

Answer (score 0):

Service is child of [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context) class, that would provide you context when you need. **It behaves like an activity (child of context too.)**

So same like **Activity**, you can call `this` or `yourService.this`(in anonymus class) keyword as a context.

Answer (score 0):

In `updateList()` you do this:

```
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

`context` is a member variable of your `Service`. However, you never initialize this variable to anything. Therefore it is `null`, which will cause the error you describe.

Answer (score -1):

Sevices has his own context. There is easy way to have an globl context.

```
private Context context;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    context = this;
}
```

That's all. Should work, if not let search an problem in other place.

@Edit

For clarity, your problem causes this line, because your context is not assigned, and it's null.

```
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```